# Create khmer Unicode supported PDF doc in android

Tags: android

I want to create a PDF document which can show khmer language.

I have used iText, droidtext, aspose etc as PDF creation library and used khmerOS, hanuman etc. as font.

But the problem is it can't display khmer words in proper order and can't combine conjunct letter 
properly. Also it shows a plus symbol, bottom of a letter in case of conjunct letter.

http://ask.osify.com/qa/613

The given link shows an image where there is a plus sign at the bottom of last character.
Is there any solution?